# SQLalchemy top 3 results from each category

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a models:

```
class Contract(ContractJsonSerializer, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'contracts'

    id = db.Column(db.Unicode(32), primary_key=True)
    device_name = db.Column(db.Unicode(256), nullable=False)
    monthly_price = db.Column(db.Numeric(precision=6, scale=2))
    network_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('networks.id'))

class Network(NetworkJsonSerializer, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'networks'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(20), nullable=False)
    contracts = db.relationship('Contract', backref='network')
```

How can I get 3 cheapest contracts from each network?

I got following SQL:

```
  set @num := 0, @network := '';

  select *
  from 
  (
     select *, 
        @num := if(@network = network_id, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
        @network := network_id as dummy
    from contracts
    order by network_id, monthly_price
  ) as x 
  where x.row_number <= 3;
```

But when I'm trying to execute it I'm getting:

```
contracts = Contract.query.from_statement(sql).all()
```

"ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically."

Can I do it in declarative way? If not what is the best way of approaching this problem?

Comment: which database do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After few hours of google & sqlalchemy docs I've got this:

```
# create query order by monthly price 
base_query = Contract.query.order_by(Contract.monthly_price)

# build subqueries for each network 
queries = []
for n in networks.all():
    queries.append( base_query.filter(Contract.network_id==n.id).\
                        limit(3).subquery().select() )

# get contracts using union_all
contracts = Contract.query.select_entity_from(union_all( *queries )).all()
```

It seems to work correctly - returning 3 cheapest contracts for each network in one query.